# Hold an inconsistent manager to their word

Tags: management, united-kingdom

**TL;DR**

There is a disconnect between what my boss (Manager X) remembers and what the rest of the team see and hear. Regardless of what was agreed or discussed in the past, even when it is in writing, what he later recalls can be substantially different.

How can I hold a manager demonstrating a lack of consistency in their actions to account?

**Background**

Examples of the Manager X's behaviour include that he will:

- frequently deny receiving emails regarding important topics (HR
  issues, project updates) then become agitated about not being kept in
  the loop when something goes wrong. I've never met anyone else who
  has so many 'issues' with lost emails as Manager X.
- remember the outcome of meetings differently from everyone else in
  the room. Even when actions are written down and circulated
  immediately after the meeting, Manager X will dispute what was agreed
  at a later point in time. We've had instances where the entire team
  agree what was discussed at the previous meeting, only for Manager X
  to reprimand the team for not completing an important task that was
  never discussed.
- tell other people (particularly his boss) what was discussed at
  meetings he was invited to but did not attend.
- mis-remember key points from discussions, even when what he remembers
  is illogical. For example, we agreed to hire a consultant for
  £800/day, confirmed in a written quote sent to Manager X and myself.
  Manager X signed the purchase agreement, the consultant completed the
  work and issued an invoice. Manager X was the furious because he
  thought the agreed rate was £125/day, and consequently our team had
  spent over the allocated budget. After Manager X claimed to have
  never seen the original quote, the consultant pointed out that
  £125/day was less than the company pays the most junior engineers
  (let alone experienced consultants) hence it made no sense to ever
  think £125/day was the agreed rate.

We try to deal with Manager X's lack of consistency by asking for everything in writing or sending emails multiple times until you get a response. Most of the time the request is ignored, or met with a harsh "don't you trust me" or "I don't have time for that" response. This approach isn't proving to be effective.

I've been tempted to think it's an easy way for Manager X to lay blame for any mistake on another team member. But at this stage I don't really care for the reason, I'd just like to put in place an approach for making sure there's some consistency between one week and the next.

Comment: Does the e-mail system you are using support automatic receipts?

Comment: It's unrealistic to expect that anything you and your coworkers do or say will have an impact. Update your resume and move on.

Comment: 'or met with a harsh "don't you trust me"' Well his memory is clearly not trustworthy, at least.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: My company tried to use automatic read receipts. They quickly discovered my habit of replying to unread emails with body quotations.

Comment: At this stage it sounds very much like your boss is suffering from some form of mental illness.

Comment: You have my empathy! I was a consultant to a global financial organization that grants loans to countries, please do not guess which one. I worked on a project where the manager placed high within the organization would tell three people standing in his office three different requirements and would even change the requirements before we left the office. It was almost impossible to pin down what the target was. In the end, I got it done and moved on. It may be that you need to move on too. But try HR first, quietly, confidentially, with an eye on solving a problem. Cheers!!

Comment: There are people who will tell everybody what they want to hear, and remember only things that fits into their current, ever changing plans. Only thing you can do is either get rid of them, or run.

Comment: Not sure that it's a good idea since nothing seems to work and is more invasive than written notes. But if your boss contests the written documentation, you could start recording the meetings with a dictaphone. This in combination with @Richard U's respone might be an idea.

Comment: Could you perhaps use a ticketing system for these things? Everything discussed in meetings gets written up as a ticket. `Manager X` needs to OK tickets. That should be a better paper trail, and directly linkable to his boss if the need arises.

Comment: A different question - is there any evidence of a change in the manager?  As in - was this always a problem, or do people who were there a couple years ago say it was different then?  This could actually be evidence of an illness that needs treating, in which case addressing it could be very helpful for your manager personally as well as professionally.

Comment: this person should not be a manager.  it's risky, but maybe you should go over his/her head.

Comment: In relational abuse situations, what you are describing is called gaslighting.  Basically the abuser makes the abused not trust their own common sense/memory/themselves by by trying to twist or alter past events.  It is a terrible place to be.  You are doing the right thing by documenting (and escalating) but don't forget to take care of your own mental health and bail if you need to.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Playing devil's advocate for a moment before answering...

> frequently deny receiving emails regarding important topics

Happens all the time when you get tons more email than you can possibly cope with.

> remember the outcome of meetings differently from everyone else in the room

Also happens all the time, and usually is a sign you're overworked and burning out. (Or dumb, but usually the former.)

> tell other people (particularly his boss) what was discussed at meetings he was invited to but did not attend.

Is a manager's job, assuming of course that what gets reported is correct.

> mis-remember key points from discussions, even when what he remembers is illogical.

Misremembering happens, though not often when you're signing proposals.

---

Memory loss, as an aside, is a [sign of burnout](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/lifestyle/warning-you-have-entered-the-burnout-zone.html). And in the last two paragraphs of your question, you make it sound like your manager is *completely* overwhelmed or burnt out. (Or, your manager might be a monstrous micromanager... it's really hard to say. But my own guess is burnout.)

---

Which brings us to your actual question:

> I'd just like to put in place an approach for making sure there's some consistency between one week and the next.

You can probably help out by making your manager's life *easier* instead of harder. Besides bringing up the burnout question upfront (with him or her), try to do your best to manage yourself to the point of being nearly or entirely autonomous. Examples:

- The task itself is vague or unclear? Expand a bit on what you feel the task is, what it's for, etc. in writing, and submit that for review.
- Next steps are vague or unclear? Expand on the DoD (Definition of Done), itemize the way forward, and submit those for review.
- Does the usefulness of this/that new feature sound fishy? Ask about it. Not satisfied with the answer? Ask if they don't mind you getting in a Hangout with a few end-users to validate the idea's merit? Assuming they accept, then do so and report on your findings.

More generally: try to produce docs that are scannable with a *short* TL;DR exec summary. They should only require a minute or two of attention unless your boss wants to dig deeper, and they should beg for a yes|no type of answer instead of a sophisticated replies.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, even if it is burnout, the manager's response is completely inappropriate. The proper response to burn out is to make it clear to your boss that you have too much work on your plate and figure out a way to lessen the load, not get angry at or blame the people you manage. Good to consider the possibility, though. +1

Comment: I think that being dumb or burned out should be somehow possible to distinguish by other means. +1 that reaction to his own forgetfulness or misunderstanding is the key. It usually not the problem but the reaction to the problem that makes a good manager.

Comment: Re: the 4th point, it's irresponsible for a *anyone* to report (with ann appearance of authority) what happened in a meeting if they did not attend. They can pass along recorded minutes, but reporting on the event without actually being there amounts to hearsay and something **will** be miscommunicated.

Comment: Making mistakes is human. Denying that you have made a mistake when one is clearly pointed out to you is incompetence.

Comment: @jpatokal - Incompetence, or full blown exhaustion... For all we know OP's boss might be an overworked nervous wreck that's in dire need for some vacation, and needs help from a shrimp. (Also, we only have OP's version of what happened.)

Comment: I also need help from a shrimp.

Comment: Heh, damn auto-correct. s/shrimp/shrink/ of/c.

Comment: @jpmc26: "Inappropriate" makes it sound like you're assuming and implying that people know when they're burnt out (or for that matter, depressed), or that they've the financial backbone to just stop working for a while to rest. Oftentimes they unfortunately aren't, and engage in behaviors that are - indeed - inappropriate or downright dangerous for themselves or the company. It's really not simple... (Also, food for thought: OP only gave his version.)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy There is no excuse for causing someone else misery and problems, even your own hard times. Does it happen? Of course. Is it okay or acceptable? Forgivable, but not acceptable. If the OP's boss is often finding that his perception of reality does not square with his employees' and with the *hard evidence* (e-mails, signed agreements), that should be a cue for some introspection. Only a sustained refusal to admit that you're wrong or something of the like would cause the kind of action described in this post. The avoidance of putting things in writing also indicates awareness.

Comment: @jpmc26: Fair enough, and agreed it's not acceptable. Just pointing out two things. 1. A nervous wreck doesn't always realize that they're engaging in sociopathic and unacceptable behavior. 2. OP's desiderata _could_ also be a sign that he needs a lot of (micro-)management. Without OP's boss' version, no one can say what the issue really is. (I once worked with a chap - an engineer w/ an MBA - who was whining constantly. Truth was, he couldn't put 2+2 together, and neither I nor his next boss had the time to walk him through everything he should do, baby step by baby step, every single day.)

Comment: Not saying OP is necessarily a whiner in need of more micromanagement than his boss can deliver, of course. Just saying that it doesn't seem right to take OP's version of what happened at face value and engage in mob justice. From where I'm standing the signs seem to point toward a boss that needs to go on a lengthy vacation and return to work with less stuff dumped on his lap.

Comment: @jpmc26: `The proper response to burn out is to make it clear to your boss that you have too much work on your plate and figure out a way to lessen the load` If the manager was capable of self-assessing burnout and figuring out a way to lessen the load; then he wouldn't be going through a burnout. The whole point of getting burnt out is that you don't know when to pull the emergency brake when you need to. Blaming others is never good; but the manager might genuinely not feel burnt out (even if he is). Some people just become hard to deal with (similar to a child that is really tired).

Comment: @Flater I have higher expectations of a manager than I do a three year old. I'm not saying it's easy; I'm saying that this isn't an acceptable way of responding. Even if the manager doesn't know how to deal with burn out, they should know better than to get angry with and blame their subordinates. If they don't know that much, they're not qualified to be a manager.

Comment: @jpmc26: You're bordering close on basically telling a depressed person that they should stop being sad. Managers are just people too. People get burnt out _because_ they can't cope with stress. Odds are they're not going to have the luxury of taking a step back and getting a fresh look on things, or they wouldn't be in this place in the first place.

Comment: @Flater No, I'm telling them not to mistreat other people, which isn't acceptable even if you're depressed. If a person can't behave professionally at their job and won't get help, then forcing them into a position where they have no choice but to seek help or at least a less stressful situation is the best thing the company can do for them. And certainly one of their superiors in the company telling them, "This is a problem. It's not acceptable and must not continue. It needs to be addressed immediately," is a good step for them as well. Ignoring the problem helps no one.

Answer (score 77):

For someone like this, where common practices such as getting things in writing or confirming receipt are not working, there is not much to do.  It sounds like you already have plenty of documentation (e.g. signed purchase order with the 800 pound / day rate) of his behavior.  I think at this point you need to initiate a discussion either directly with him or with his boss about his behavior and how it impacts your work.

Comment: And before any conversation, make sure to talk to your coworkers, since this affects them too. You don't want to bring a large group of people into a meeting, otherwise it feels like you're ganging up on him, but you can say "coworkers A, B and C all agree with me". Just make sure ahead of time that they will back you up if confronted about it.

Comment: Make sure your coworkers actually have your back and aren't going to bail out like wimps.

Comment: Ganging up seems the right thing to do here. Don't act alone if you're not the only one with the problem.

Comment: `... initiate a discussion either directly with him...` I'm not confident that he'll stick to whatever is agreed in that discussion. Go to his boss directly (but as others have pointed out, maybe the uberboss is either unwilling or unable to fix the problem)

Comment: I might also include HR in the conversation. It is possible that the problem manager is not deflecting but honestly doesn't remember these discussions/emails. If you can phrase the discussion such that you are not only concerned about your team's ability to perform their jobs but that the team is also concerned about the manager's health, that might be more well received.

Answer (score 45):

Document everything, and CC manager X's boss.  For important emails, send it with receipt requested, so you have the proof.  Start CCing his boss on even trivial emails so that this erratic behavior becomes apparent.

If he reprimands people for things not done that were never mentioned, escalate.

The real problem is that **his** boss needs to start holding him to account, the only way to do that is to help his boss build a file on him.  Again, document everything, and make sure his boss is kept in the loop.

Comment: CC'ing the boss's boss on anything, especially trivial unrelated things, does not sound like a good idea..  It sounds like there is already plenty of evidence (e.g. signed purchase order at 800 pounds / day) of the boss's behavior.

Comment: Contact the boss's boss, yes. Pro ide evidence at that time. Don't cc unless s/he tells you to.

Comment: I do this at my job; we call it CYA "Cover Your Ass"

Comment: @Eric no, it's an excellent idea.  If you think it's a bad  idea because the boss's boss won't like getting trivial emails, that's the entire point of escalating.  Boss X is trashing their reputations to the point where bigboss probably believes at least SOME of what's going on.  It's got to be escalated or nothing will change.

Comment: `The real problem is that his boss needs to start holding him to account,`  +1 for that bit, not that it matters.  If the boss's boss hasn't done so already, he probably never will.  There's a reason this manager is able to get away with this kind of ridiculous behavior (like going 6+ times over budget and excusing it by claiming to have hired a consultant without getting the bill rate), and it doesn't reflect well on *his* boss at all.

Comment: @HopelessN00b you'd be surprised at how good sociopaths are at blamestorming, and how good they are at keeping their bosses in the dark.

Comment: You CC your boss's boss to make your boss look good, not bad. If he thinks that your motive is to make him look bad, you're going to regret it, especially if you want to keep working there.

Comment: @AaronHall The boss is already making life miserable.  I was in this situation once, got the SOB terminated.

Comment: That sounds like a very interesting story. However, it seems to me that your advice could well get the asker terminated or at a minimum make his life miserable.

Comment: @AaronHall It sounds like his boss is already trying to set him and/or others up to take the fall.  When it gets to that point, you have nothing to lose.  And yes, the guy tried to make my life difficult in retaliation.  If he wants to stop the boss, he should do this, if not he should update his resume and move on.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Completely agreed that the boss's boss won't be any help. But please, don't use code boxes for quotation: use quotation marks for that. Code formatting doesn't just change how the text *looks*, it changes what the computer thinks the text *is* – and that can mess with non-visual browsers, like screen-readers for the blind, which try to treat such text as appropriate for code (including, in some cases, reading it out letter-by-letter). Using code formatting for non-code makes the site less accessible for disabled users.

Comment: This is bad advice in my opinion. CC spam creates an environment of mistrust, hostility, and stress. It borders on sociopathic, and could get you terminated in sane organizations.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy that environment already exists and the OP is dealing with a sociopath.  What's your solution?

Comment: @RichardU: My own reading of OP's question is that OP's boss is a nervous wreck that either needs help to work less and/or some much needed vacation. But frankly, I'm also suspecting that there's more to it than what OP wrote.

Comment: @RichardU what kind of "termination" are we talking about? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

While getting things in writing is good, just asking for things in writing is not good enough. There are 2 more things to do:

- Understand why things are put in writing. It's to resolve simple misunderstandings, but if the problem is more than just a simple misunderstanding - as is the case in your scenario - the purpose of a written record is so outsiders can come in, read the written records, and have an idea what's going on; who to believe.
- If you either don't get things in writing, or the things in writing do not match events as you experienced them, you need to put things in writing yourself. Send a short email:

  > As discussed, [summary of discussion], [summary of actions you will perform], [summary of actions recipient is expected to perform].

  And when you write things down, you write down not just the original agreement, but you also write down how the boss changes his mind, and you write down his statements that contradict your previous records. No need to spell out that the boss changes his mind or that he contradicts himself, writing down the boss' new decision or the boss' new claim is sufficient.

If there are repeated misunderstandings which are not resolved by showing the written record, chances are there is a medical condition causing memory loss - some of which are life threatening - so you absolutely must contact HR with a medical concern. Don't try to save reputations by avoiding HR when someone's life is at risk.